# How would I rank within a groupby object based on another row condition in Pandas? Example included

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The dataframe below has 4 columns: runner_name,race_date, height_in_inches,top_ten_finish.

I want to groupby race_date, and if the runner finished in the top ten for that race_date, rank his height_in_inches among only the other runners who finished in the top ten for that race_date. How would I do this?

This is the original dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {"runner":['mike','paul','jim','dave','douglas'],
...     "race_date":['2019-02-02','2019-02-02','2020-02-02','2020-02-01','2020-02-01'],
...      "height_in_inches":[72,68,70,74,73],
...     "top_ten_finish":["yes","yes","no","yes","no"]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
    runner   race_date  height_in_inches top_ten_finish
0     mike  2019-02-02                72            yes
1     paul  2019-02-02                68            yes
2      jim  2020-02-02                70             no
3     dave  2020-02-01                74            yes
4  douglas  2020-02-01                73             no
>>>
```

and this is what I'd like the result to look like. Notice how if they didn't finish in the top 10 of a race, they get a value of 0 for that new column.

```
    runner   race_date  height_in_inches top_ten_finish  if_top_ten_height_rank
0     mike  2019-02-02                72            yes                       1
1     paul  2019-02-02                68            yes                       2
2      jim  2020-02-02                70             no                       0
3     dave  2020-02-01                74            yes                       1
4  douglas  2020-02-01                73             no                       0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

We can do `groupby` + filter with `rank`

```
df['rank']=df[df.top_ten_finish.eq('yes')].groupby('race_date')['height_in_inches'].rank(ascending=False)
df['rank'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
df
Out[87]: 
    runner   race_date  height_in_inches top_ten_finish  rank
0     mike  2019-02-02                72            yes   1.0
1     paul  2019-02-02                68            yes   2.0
2      jim  2020-02-02                70             no   0.0
3     dave  2020-02-01                74            yes   1.0
4  douglas  2020-02-01                73             no   0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter and rank on `groupby()` then assign back:

```
df['if_top_ten_height_rank'] = (df.loc[df['top_ten_finish']=='yes','height_in_inches']
                                   .groupby(df['race_date']).rank(ascending=False)
                                   .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
                                   .astype(int)
                                )
```

Output:

```
    runner    race_date      height_in_inches  top_ten_finish      if_top_ten_height_rank
--  --------  -----------  ------------------  ----------------  ------------------------
 0  mike      2019-02-02                   72  yes                                      1
 1  paul      2019-02-02                   68  yes                                      2
 2  jim       2020-02-02                   70  no                                       0
 3  dave      2020-02-01                   74  yes                                      1
 4  douglas   2020-02-01                   73  no                                       0
```